# How to switch data save location to Firestore database?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I study CRUD below sample.

https://flutterawesome.com/firebase-crud-operation-in-flutter/

and this is github page

https://github.com/Justin-roy/Firebase-Crud-Operation?ref=flutterawesome.com

I can CRUD at my Physical cellphone. And I would like to go
next step that Firestore database connect.

I'm trying to connect to Firestore database.
but seems like this app to save data somewhere(not firestore)
I see 'Students' is table. but I'm not sure where it connect to.

I wrote below.

main.dart

```
Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

And this is
add.dart file's Add part

```
  //Resigtering Users
  CollectionReference addUser =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Students');
  Future<void> _registerUser() {
    return addUser
        .add({'Name': name, 'Email': email, 'Password': password})
        .then((value) => print('User Added'))
        .catchError((_) => print('Something Error In registering User'));
  }
```

Here is my current Firestore page.
I click start connection. and type 'Students' and made Name, Email, Password name and length.
[image]

Then I run this app.
I can CRUD data but seems like the data are stored not Firestore database.
I don't know where data goes.
When I create data I can save it but I got I got this error.

> W/Firestore(22295): (24.4.1) [WriteStream]: (fc48c10) Stream closed
> with status: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Permission
> denied on resource project curd-23d4e., cause=null}.

Could you teach me how to switch to it please?

UPDATE

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your firebase firestore, click on "Rules" then, you should see this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

Update it so:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Then you should see a `publish` button, press it.

Comment: Dear Josteve Thank you for answering me. I used your code. I create data but I got I got this error . W/Firestore(28251): (24.4.1) [WriteStream]: (1f21617) Stream closed with status: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Permission denied on resource project curd-23d4e., cause=null}

Comment: If the rules was published, are you sure your flutter projected is connected to this firebase project?

Comment: Dear Josteve. I'm sorry I don't get your mean. I don't mind to published this app and those data. This is just my flutter and firestore study. I just would like to see how flutter this app and firestore are connected.

Comment: I mean publishing the rules on your firebase console.

Comment: Sorry ...  still I don't understand that mean.

Comment: Hi @bluetail, I updated my answer, please check it.

Comment: Dear Josteve sorry I took long. I use your update code. I don't see  publishsh button but the message say This will publish around 1min. so It sesms publishing. but I got same error still.